# Can someone help me with arrays in c#?

Tags: c#, arrays, dataset, format

Well basicly had some trouble with placing my teams like so: http://pastebin.com/ahgP04bU

So I asked someone for advice and he just gave me a tip. And he said it has something to do with arrays. Follwing that he sended me a this code...

```
  string[,] clubs = new string[20,30];

  clubs[0,1] = “spain”;

  clubs[0,2] = etc;
```

What I don't understand is those comma's. And what does that [20,30] indicate? 
And how does this help me place my teams in the way I want it (look on the pastebin link).

Or if you think you have a better link for me to help me out with arrays in datasets I would appreciate it.

best regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`new string[20,30]` creates a new multi-dimensional array. Where 20 indicates the array-width and 30 the array-height. Think of it like this:

If you create an array with the width 5 and height 5, you are basically creating 5*5 "slots" for strings that you can set. You can access a specific slot by its coordinates.

This code:

```
string[,] clubs = new string[5,5];
clubs[0, 1] = "a";
clubs[1, 4] = "b";
clubs[3, 2] = "c";
```

Creates an array like this:

```
    0   1   2   3   4
0   ""  ""  ""  ""  ""
1   "a" ""  ""  ""  ""
2   ""  ""  ""  "c" ""
3   ""  ""  ""  ""  ""
4   ""  "b" ""  ""  ""
```

Comment: hmm you and femaref have different opiniuns on what [0, 1] does. Could you tell if u made a typo or he did?

Comment: Oh and another thing - Does clubs mean "datatable clubs"?

Comment: In a c# array you access a specific element in it with the following syntax: array[column, row] or array[x,y]. So i think Femaref made a typo. And "clubs" is just another way of saying "teams".

Comment: no i know that clubs is another way of saying teams. But in the programming way. Does it say: in the datatable clubs there are 5 columns and 5 rows.

Comment: Yeah you can say it is a club-datatable with 5 columns are 5 rows.

Answer (score 3):

That is a two-dimensional array, you can imagine them like a table. The first index is the row, the second is the column.

```
     0 1 2 3 4 5 6
---|----------------
 0 |   x
 1 |
 2 |
 3 |
```

The element denoted by the `x` would be `[0,1]`.

Comment: But how is 0,1,2,3 on x devined ? Like the first one on the row list is automaticly 0 and then follows 1 and so on?

Comment: I don't really understand your question, could you specify it?

Comment: Ye i know the answer of my question now - But the problem is you and Lukas K have different positioning with the same array. Could you tell who is making a mistake here?

Comment: He does, the first index is the row, and the second is the column. At least in C#.

Answer (score 0):

It a 2 way multi diamensional array.

refer to [msdn for more information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

First number means number of rows, second columns

string [,] myArray = new string[2,3]

would be 2 rows & 3 columns